# Issue with keeping a static variable correctly updated throughout objects

Tags: java, object, static-variables

I want to have a variable that counts all of the number of employees throughout all of the created objects in main. Here is how far I've got:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Department dep1 = new Department();
        Department dep2 = new Department("CSTI", 30);
        dep1.setEmp(20);
        dep2.setEmp(40);
        System.out.println(dep1.totalNumEmp);
        // Outputs 60
        dep1 = dep2; // here is where I get lost
        dep1.setEmp(10);
        System.out.println(dep1.numEmp + " " + dep2.numEmp);// outputs 10 10
        System.out.println(dep1.totalNumEmp);// Outputs 30. When it needs to output 20, because dep1 and dep2 are now
                                                // both 10
    }
}

class Department {

    String name;
    int numEmp;

    public static int totalNumEmp;

    Department() {
    }

    Department(String newName, int newNum) {
        name = newName;
        numEmp = newNum;
        totalNumEmp += numEmp;
    }

    public void setEmp(int newNum) {
        totalNumEmp -= numEmp;
        numEmp = newNum;
        totalNumEmp += numEmp;
    }
}
```

My issue is that I have no clue on how I'm supposed to keep totalNumEmp updated correctly once `dep1 = dep2`. I have to figure out a way to keep `totalNumEmp` updated correctly after `dep1` is pointed to `dep2`'s reference. I know I could easily do `dep1.setEmp(dep2.numEmp)` and avoid it messing up `totalNumEmp`, but I have to know how to do it with `dep1` pointing to `dep2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'll keep things as simple as possible. No need for data encapsulation, patterns, concurrency or whatever. Keep it as simple as possible while learning the basics.

First of all, you need to understand what you're doing.

> our teacher wants us to have a variable that counts all of the number
>   of employees...

Here I see a `Department` class, with a `setEmp` method, which seems it increments the count of the employees on every call. I don't think this is what your teacher meant with

> ...throughout all of the created objects in main.

What your teacher most probably wants you to do is have two classes (I assume you created  `Department` for a reason):

```
Employee
```

which is assigned to a

```
Department
```

---

Again

> ...counts all of the number of employees throughout all of the created
>   objects in main

We can interpret this in two ways

1. Your teacher wants you to count all the created `Employee`s (as question title suggests)
2. Your teacher wants you to count all the `Employee`s per `Department`

Let's start with option **1**

I'll skip the `Department` class as it's not really in scope, and I'll go directly to the *created employee count*.
What the assigned task would say is just to count the created objects, which means the created `Employee`s.

Here is what the `Employee` class might look like

```
public class Employee {
   // Count of the created employees
   public static int count = 0;

   // ... Class fields

   public Employee(
       final Department department,
       final String name,
       final String surname) {
      // ... Assign arguments to class fields

      // A new employee has been created. Increment the counter!
      ++count;    
   }

   ... 
}
```

This static field

```
public static int count = 0;
```

is incremented each time a new `Employee` is created.
You'll be able to access it via

```
final int total = Employee.count;
```

---

Now, option **2**

As you need to count `Employee`s per `Department`, you need to increment a sort of count inside the `Department` class. Here is what the `Department` class might look like then

```
public class Department {
   private final List<Employee> employees;
   private final String name;

   public Department(final String name) {
      this.employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
      return employees;
   }

   public int getEmployeeCount() {
      return employees.size();
   }

   public void addEmployee(final Employee employee) {
      employees.add(employee);
   }
}
```

You can see that this class owns

- a name
- the list of the assigned employees  (`private final List<Employee> employees`)

Then, we have the `Employee` class, like the one I described above, but watch out for the changes

```
public class Employee {
   // ... Class fields

   public Employee(
       final String name,
       final String surname) {
      // ... Assign arguments to class fields
   }

   ... 
}
```

Here we have just a normal class (a *Pojo*). How do we use it? Follow in-code comments

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
   final Department dep1 = new Department("dep1");
   dep1.addEmployee(new Employee("Name1", "Surname1"));
   dep1.addEmployee(new Employee("Name2", "Surname2"));

   final Department dep2 = new Department("dep2");
   dep2.addEmployee(new Employee("Name3", "Surname3"));

   // Now we have two departments.
   // We can retrieve the count of employees for each using
   final int dep1Count = dep1.getEmployeeCount();
   final int dep2Count = dep2.getEmployeeCount();

   // And we can have the total
   final int total = dep1Count + dep2Count;
}
```

---

I haven't included objects or topics about synchronization or concurrency, as I think you're still at the beginning and don't need to get confused with that stuff.

Comment: Thank you, your response helped alot!

Comment: @AidanHigginbotham No problem :) You can tweak my code per your specific needs now, but you've got a solid starting point.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(dep1.totalNumEmp) is printing 30 because the variable totalNumEmp is static at model Department.

Why do you want to have the total eployees of all departments at dep1.totalNumEmp? In mi mind, you cant keep the total employess of all departments in one instance of Department model because each model should contain your own data.

To count the total employees you should make something like:

```
Integer totalEmployees = dept1.totalNumEmp + dept2.totalNumEmp;
```

Obs: I recommend you to use Get pattern to access data in models and dont keep the private fields with "public" modifier.
Ex:

```
Integer totalEmployees = dept1.getTotalNumEmp() + dept2.getTotalNumEmp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the totalNumEmp variable, its useless and doesn't belong to the departments in object oriented programming, because it is not an attribute of each of the departements.

In your main, create an arraylist of your departments

```
ArrayList<Departments> allDepartments = new ArrayList<>();
allDepartments.add(dep1);
allDepartments.add(dep2);
//...
```

and then create a static method which will count your total number of employees:

```
private static int countTotalNum(ArrayList<Departments> allDepartments) {
    AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger();
    allDepartments.forEach(department -> sum.addAndGet(department.numEmp));
    return sum.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you have structured your code: you are changing value of `totalNumEmp` in the `setEmp()` setter and both static field and setter belong to the same class.

Because of this, the following:

```
dep1 = dep2;     // here dep1 starts referencing dep2
dep1.setEmp(10);
```

will actually execute the setter once (which is probably what you wanted) but `totalNumEmp` will also be changed only once (and you except it to be changed twice, to correctly set `totalNumEmp` to 20).

I would recommend changing the following in your design:

1. Keep `totalNumEmp` in a separate class or generate it on the fly.
2. Don't do this, as this is bad practice: `dep1 = dep2`. Use copying contructor instead (`public Department(Department other)`).
3. Think about concurrency, e.g. consider using `AtomicInteger` instead of `int` or synchronization.